# Lots of lag and log in loop

Tags: 18.04, 64-bit, nvidia-geforce

Update: I'm sad that my post wasn't answered sooner, but I figured out that ".xauthority" was causing the issue. I watch a video that has me do 1 command in `ctrl alt F1` which In turn fixed the lag and the login loop. I am now able to use Ubuntu normal with no issues.

`$ mv .Xauthority .Xauthority.bak` that's the command.

I've decided to switch from Windows to Ubuntu. I used Ubuntu before, so I know basic commands and other stuff; but this completely goes over my head...

I get a lot of lag on the login page. I'm able to move my mouse around but as soon as I bring it over the middle of the screen to highlight my name  to login, it lags a lot. My computer hangs for a few seconds to actually bring up my prompt to put my password in.
Additionally when I actually logged in, my screen goes black and goes right back to my log in screen.

But, I'm able to login into the Wayland version of the desktop, even though it lags horribly.

I've already done `sudo apt-get update` and `upgrade` with no improvements over the issue.

I downloaded Ubuntu version: Ubuntu LTS 18.04 amd64

My pc specs:

- Intel core i5 2400
- 8gbs ddr 3
- Nvidia GT1030 gddr5 version
- 1tb hard drive

Hopefully this gets figured out because at the current state I'm unable to use my main device any more.